# "How interruptions are going to be handled?" versus "How are interruptions going to be handled?"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Are *How interruptions are going to be handled?* and *How are interruptions going to be handled?* both correct?

If yes, then is there a difference in meaning? What form is used more often and in what situations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions without reordering the sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63159/questions-without-reordering-the-sentence)

Comment: *How interruptions are going to be handled* is a ***noun phrase*** - in "question" contexts, it's syntactically equivalent to, say, the pronoun in *"I don't know **him**".* Hence we might use it in a *statement* such as *"I don't know **how interruptions are going to be handled**"*. Note that noun phrases like that can be included in questions featuring inversion of a *different* subject/verb pair, as in the question: *"**Does he know** how interruptions are going to be handled?"*. To which a possible "statement" reply is: *"**He does know** how interruptions are going to be handled".*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now I know why they both sounded correct to me. I guess I heard these types of phrases in questions that _already_ inversed the subject/verb order somewhere else and I got the wrong idea. Thank you.

Comment: Remember that the final item in my comment can easily *become* a question simply by being spoken with "rising intonation" (and *optionally* ending with a "question tag"): *"He does know how interruptions are going to be handled, **doesn't he**?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is incorrect.

As a general rule, questions invert the word order to put the verb first.

The second form is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and standard form for asking this question in English is "How are interruptions going to be handled?" This construction follows the conventional English question format of placing the auxiliary verb ("are") before the subject ("interruptions").

The phrase "Are how interruptions are going to be handled?" is not grammatically correct in standard English. It appears to mix two different question structures, leading to confusion and making the sentence difficult to understand.

Therefore, when forming questions, especially in formal writing or speech, it's important to adhere to the standard structure to ensure clarity and correct grammar.

Answer (score -1):

> how interruptions are going to be handled

That is not a question, but a kind of content clause.

> How are interruptions going to be handled?

That is a question.

The first might be a section header in a document:

> HOW INTERRUPTIONS ARE GOING TO BE HANDLED
>
> The interrupting person, the "heckler", will be forcibly removed from the auditorium. His family will be harassed, his home fire-bombed, and the Department of Justice will make his life a living hell.